# Appboy-iOS-SDK/AppboyKit.h not found

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, appboy, braze

I have installed Appboy 2.22 using CocoaPods.

I'm getting the following error in my AppDelegate when I try to `#import "Appboy-iOS-SDK/AppboyKit.h"`:

> Appboy-iOS-SDK/AppboyKit.h not found.

Comment: check your linked library search path and target added properly or not

Comment: All ok in my project.

Comment: Can take a try with angular brace like #import <Appboy-iOS-SDK/AppboyKit.h>. Let me know if it works

Comment: I am using this buddy.

Comment: Is this a Swift app or Obj-C? The process of importing would be different in both. A Swift project would need you to use a bridging header. And did you run a `pod install` after adding the pod?

Comment: objective c, I have update my podfile by adding appboy to podfile

Comment: Hi Anand - can you try adding it like https://github.com/Appboy/appboy-ios-sdk/blob/master/HelloAppboy/HelloAppboy/AppDelegate.h#L2

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are using Ruby 2.0.0 or higher.
To check, run `ruby -v` in terminal.
If ruby needs to be updated, follow instructions [here](http://codingpad.maryspad.com/2017/04/29/update-mac-os-x-to-the-current-version-of-ruby/).

Next, make sure that your Podfile includes `pod 'Appboy-iOS-SDK'` for all applicable targets. Then run 'pod install' in terminal.

For more details, Braze has setup instructions for Appbor-iOS-SDK using CocoaPods [here](https://www.braze.com/docs/developer_guide/platform_integration_guides/ios/initial_sdk_setup/initial_sdk_setup/#ios--sdk-cocoapod-integration).

Hope this helps.